# Printing Div with Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am working on an MVC C# app wherein the contents of a div are composed with an AJAX call that retrieves database fields and returned as the success message to JavaScript. The string (a trivial example):

```
"<div style='background:yellow'>asdf<img src='myfile.jpg'></div>"
```

is then printed with:

```
function printDivContents(contents) {
    var printContents = contents;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = "<div style='margin:10px'>" + printContents + "</div>";
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Everything prints perfectly in most cases, but there is an image in there that prints if and only if it has been loaded previously. I would like it to always print. I have tried adding a preloading script to the content string. I can only use pure JavaScript, not jQuery, and all CSS has to be inline. What are my options to get the image to load? Should I pause execution to wait for the DOM to load, assign the image as a hidden div background on the calling page, or...?

Comment: Does the AJAX response give you the content string fully? It may be better to expect a JSON response, and if an "image" object is found you'd be able to create the new "img" node and load the image with `img.src = "myfile.jpg"`. Let me know if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Tyler, yes, the AJAX gives the full content string. While seperation of concerns would place DOM creation in the view, it would be a substantial project to move the code from server-side to JavaScript. After writing my question, I tried adding the image to a hidden div in the calling page, and it works perfectly...the only challenge is that the image is now hardcoded and therefore can't be changed dynamically. I'm still working on that part. This question is solved (hidden div background), but I'll keep it up in case somebody else has the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Wes. What I'm ultimately getting at is being able to parse the src attribute and set that programmatically. Setting it that way (after load) should display the image properly. I generally try to avoid using background:url(), but any lazy loaded hidden image could also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page that makes the initial AJAX call, create a hidden div as such:

```
<div style="display:none; background:url('myfile.jpg')"></div>
```

If the file is dynamically changed, change the background of the div prior to printing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still be able to change the image dynamically, I have had very similar issues and found that waiting for the image to load worked quite well:

```
var image = Image();
image.onload(function () {
    //print the screen, or do whatever
});
image.src = "whateverImgSrc";
```